# Pyinstaller ImportError on pywt `_ctw` module

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pywt

Pywt is not importing `_cwt` module correctly when the program is compiled with Pyinstaller.  I verified that `_cwt.py` is present in my pywt root (in site-packages on the path) and `_cwt.pyd` is in the `pywt\_extensions` dir.  I can successfully import pywt from Python.  Below is a minimum (non) working example to illustrate the `ImportError` traceback.

Program `pywt_test.py`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
try:
    import sys, traceback
    import pywt
    print pywt.__version__
except ImportError:
    type_, value_, traceback_ = sys.exc_info()
    e_msg = traceback.format_exception(type_, value_, traceback_)
    with open('pywt_error_log.txt','w') as f:
        f.write(''.join(e_msg))
```

Pyinstaller spec file `pywt_test.spec`

```
 # -*- mode: python -*-

 block_cipher = None


 a = Analysis(['pywt_test.py'],
         pathex=['C:\\Users\\user', 'C:\\Users\\user'],
         binaries=[],
         datas=[],
         hiddenimports=[],
         hookspath=[],
         runtime_hooks=[],
         excludes=[],
         win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
         win_private_assemblies=False,
         cipher=block_cipher)
 pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
         cipher=block_cipher)
 exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts,
      a.binaries,
      a.zipfiles,
      a.datas,
      name='pywt_test',
      debug=False,
      strip=False,
      upx=False,
      console=True)
```

Pyinstall compile command: `pyinstaller pywt_test.spec`.

Command ran:  `pywt_test.exe`

Contents of `pywt_error_log.txt`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pywt_test.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-3zvqo7\pyinstaller\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
  File "site-packages\pywt\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-3zvqo7\pyinstaller\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in load_module
  File "pywt\_extensions\_pywt.pyx", line 1, in init pywt._extensions._pywt (pywt\_extensions\_pywt.c:32588)
 ImportError: No module named _cwt
```

I tried adding `_cwt` to the pathex, hiddenimports, etc. None change the error.

How can I get `_cwt`, and the entire pywt package, to load with Pyinstaller?

Versions, for reference:

- Pywt:  0.5.1
- Pyinstaller: 3.2.1
- Python: 2.7.12 64bit on Windows 7 64bit (Anaconda)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add it to the hidden imports:

```
 ...
 hiddenimports=['pywt._extensions._cwt'],
 ...
```

Answer (score 2):

As *wedesoft* mentioned, adding hidden imports works. To avoid such errors in the future you might add a file

> '\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-pywt.py'

with the string:

`hiddenimports=['pywt._extensions._cwt']`

I simply took an existing file like '\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-patsy.py', changed the hiddenimports line to the one above and saved as hook-pywt.py. That should work until you update your PyInstaller.

Comment: I don't have such a file. I have a folder called py-pyinstaller but it has one file in it called portfile.

Comment: @kylefoley76 - maybe there was an installation issue with pyinstaller? Have you followed the installation (https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html)?